# Javascript fade out this span

Tags: javascript, html

I got a button with the following code:

```
<script>$('#sumbitf').click(function(){
  $('#sumbitf').fadeOut();
});</script>
<span href="#" type="sumbit" class="button2" id="sumbitf">Wrong details</span>
```

I can't figure out a way to make it fade out, when I click it it does nothing at all

Comment: Works fine, you're just running it before doc ready. Using inline JavaScript as a quick 'trick' seems bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sumbitf').click(function(){
      $('#sumbitf').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Or you can save time and do this little trick:

```
<span onClick="$(this).fadeOut()">I like peanuts</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

**When** do you call this script? You have to do it

A) in your manner after $(document).ready-Event

B) in your manner after setting the dynamically content

C) with the `.on()` method

```
$('#sumbitf').on({
  click:function(){
          //$('#sumbitf').fadeOut();
          $(this).fadeOut();
          return false;
        }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call that function when the DOM is fully loaded so do it like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#sumbitf').click(function(){
          $('#sumbitf').fadeOut();
        });

    });
</script>
```